# Div scaling based on image

Tags: html, css, scale

I am currently working on a project as part of my Digital course at school and have come across a problem.

I have my website looking how I want on a usual screen size but am looking at scaling. I have a slide show image setup inside a div and would like to keep the images aspect ratio and change the div size accordingly.  At the moment the width scales but I can't get the height to scale. I have tried adding height %'s to both of the divs in the picture below but then the div height just goes to nothing. The height is currently set at 216.9px on the slideshow which is what works for a normal screen but obviously once zoomed it gets too tall. What is my best way to fix this? Im thinking something along the lines of a max-height.

TLDR: The image is how I would like it to look when it scales. At the moment the height of the div is only done with px.

Relevant Code is below.

```css
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    11.11% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    44.44% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.fadein {
    position:relative;
}
.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 9s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.fadein img:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.fadein img:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.fadein img:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
#slideshow2 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 172px;
    background: rgb(209, 211, 214);
    background: rgba(209, 211, 214, .5);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 6px #A8A8A8;
    margin: 30px;
}
#wrap3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
                <div id="wrap3">
                    <div id="slideshow2" class="fadein">

                        <img src="../Images/MicroQuads/Microquad1.jpg" alt="First">
                        <img src="../Images/MicroQuads/Microquad2.JPG" alt="Second">
                        <img src="../Images/MicroQuads/Microquad3.JPG" alt="Third">
                    </div>
                    <div id="slideshow2" class="fadein">
                        <img src="../Images/FreeStylePictures/Freestyle1.jpg" alt="First">
                        <img src="../Images/FreeStylePictures/Freestyle2.jpg" alt="Second">
                        <img src="../Images/FreeStylePictures/Freestyle1.jpg" alt="Third">
                        <img src="../Images/FreeStylePictures/Freestyle2.jpg" alt="Fourth">
                    </div>
                    <div id="slideshow2" class="fadein">
                        <img src="../Images/Racing Quads/Race1.jpg" alt="First">
                        <img src="../Images/Racing Quads/Race2.jpg" alt="Second">
                        <img src="../Images/Racing Quads/Race3.jpg" alt="Third">
                    </div>

                </div>
```

**Target:** 
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want your height to be dynamically, you should always use height:auto;
Dont use any % or px values

Comment: Ill keep that in mind when editing my code now, but how do you suggest I impliment that for what I am trying to achieve? If I change the height to anything but a px value, the div box height goes to 0 as in the picture below. I am guessing since the img is inside of the div the div doesn't have anything to base the height of thus my problem.  [link](http://imgur.com/a/PaUHl)

Comment: if you are going to use position absolute for the image inside the div, you should add a {display:block;} to mark the border for the div and have the image positioned absolutely inside the div, not outside.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on that a bit please? I tried adding the display block to the #slideshow2 div and change the position absolute but aren't sure what exactly you're meaning. Thanks.

Comment: position absolute is a matter on the upper div, so when you use the absolute you should tell the browser its absolutely to what? so you can have the upper div or the one before or the one before the two and so by selection display:block; so browser can see where exactly you are trying to position the div..